# MySQL #1064 Error DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, syntax-error

I'm making a web based mail system, and I have to create a table with this code:

```
    CREATE TABLE 'messages'(
    'ID' INT(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'To' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'CC' VARCHAR(250),
    'BCC' VARCHAR(250),
    'From' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    'Subject' VARCHAR(250),
    'Message' LONG BLOB NOT NULL,
    'Date' DATETIME NOT NULL,
    'MailboxID' INT(250) NOT NULL,
    Primary Key ('ID'));
```

MySQL says:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''messages'( 'ID' INT(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'To' VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,' at line 1`

Might be the error is in `DATETIME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes around your column identifiers. Either use ticks or nothing at at all:

```
CREATE TABLE messages(
    ID INT(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    To VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    CC VARCHAR(250),
    BCC VARCHAR(250),
    From VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    Subject VARCHAR(250),
    Message LONG BLOB NOT NULL,
    Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    MailboxID INT(250) NOT NULL,
Primary Key (ID));
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages`(
    `ID` INT(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `To` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `CC` VARCHAR(250),
    `BCC` VARCHAR(250),
    `From` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `Subject` VARCHAR(250),
    `Message` LONG BLOB NOT NULL,
    `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `MailboxID` INT(250) NOT NULL,
Primary Key (`ID`));
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Yep. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of single quotes for all the field name in the table scema

The syntax should be

```
create table table_name
(
  col_name int(1)
  ......
  .....
);
```

So in your case it should be

```
CREATE TABLE messages(
    ID INT(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `To` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    CC VARCHAR(250),
    BCC VARCHAR(250),
    `From` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    Subject VARCHAR(250),
    Message LONG BLOB NOT NULL,
    Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    MailboxID INT(250) NOT NULL,
    Primary Key ('ID'));
```

In addition you are using reserved keyword TO and FROM so you need to backtick them as well

Answer (score 0):

You can check mysql documentation for developers about [datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).